# Insert jquery code inside same jquery file only in a determined url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, url

I have some jquery code (For a gallery) which is interacting in all my pages of my site, disturbing the layout of the site. Therefore I would like a determined jquery code to interact only in the gallery page. To avoid jquery submissions I want to keep all the jquery code in one file. Therefore I need to append, insert, add... a segment of the jquery code inside the same jquery file. For this I'm trying to use this code:

```
var url = window.location.href; // returns the full URL
  if(/gallery/.test(url)) {
    $('INSIDE THE SAME JQUERY FILE').addCONTENT('JQUERY CONTENT');
  }
```

I want to avoid creaitng another file and adding the following:

```
var url = window.location.href; // returns the full URL
      if(/gallery/.test(url)) {
        $('head').append('<script src="js/gallery.js">');
      }
```

I would like to use only one script call.

Comment: show the code of the file you want to add code to. and what is the code you want to insert

Comment: @Dvir In Line 31 you will find the comment in uppercase. The code from their below is what I want to add only if the url has gallery in it. I just do not knwo how to append the jquery code inside the same file. HEre you have the fiddle with the jquery code. http://jsfiddle.net/8zUjs/2/

Comment: Why can't you have it all in one file, and use only the parts that are needed in gallery / the rest?

Comment: @MightyPork I want to avoid using external files as maximum. So I thought that maybe there is a good method to add a certain jquery code inside the same jquery file. Is this wrong?

Comment: ok so just add the code to file as is.
remove the jquery part:
`if(/gallery/.test(window.location.href)) { //do somthing }`

Comment: you tagged your question as PHP. Why cant you put it all into a <script> tag in the page, and use PHP to optionally add/remove some parts?

Comment: @Dvir it worked! One last question. Is this method not so logic?

Comment: @MightyPork My files are all php files, thats why I tagged PHP on it. Isn't that practice not to correct? I mean to insert <script> inside the head directly... I thought it's better to have everything in external files. Maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: bad practice is using seperate files for seperate roles.
for example validation functions and objects will be in validate.js file. and graphic or gui will be in ui.js.
think about what will happen if one day you will want to change some code. you will forgot where is the code and what it was. but when your files seperate it's easier to find your code. there is a lot of advantages but read about it on google.

Comment: @Dvir I used your code and it worked. It works fine on my localhost but once I put it online it ignores completely this code. I inserted this inside a folder of my portfolio as a test. Could there be something not interacting correctly due to the fact that it's inside a folder of my online portfolio? Her eyo go the temporal url http://escuderodesign.com/examples/cepods/about.php. This code is to make the design tab only open when you have the word design inside. So the code is if(/design/.test(window.location.href)) { //do somthing }. That do something is: $('.dropli').addClass('active');

Comment: But I see it's working...

Comment: @Dvir I checked again. It adds active class to li .dropi in every page. If it was working the design menu would only open once in a url which contains the word design. At this moment the class active is being added in each page I access. For example, the link I gave you is about.php. It shouldn't open the design menu button as in the url the word design is not inserted. If the code was working it wouldn't look like this. Do you see this or maybe you have another view?! Thanks in advance, I really do not understand what is the problem.

Comment: @Dvir If interested, I just found the error. Stupid error... the code works perfectly but as I put it on my portfolio online website which is called escuderodesign.com the word design was present in the url. So the code was working perfectly. But of course my intention was it to work only when the user was on /design/ not on every page. Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: Yes i know it was that. But i thought that's what you want :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is the following:

```
if(/gallery/.test(window.location.href)) { 
    // JavaScript code you wish to add
}
```

This will add the code in the same file only if for this example you are in a URL with the word `gallery` in it.

Comment: @MightyPork Thanks for that... By the way, just to get better, is my idea not good practice, or your idea with the PHP insert, is it not a good practice? Just to know for a future...

Comment: I don't like this approach, since it depends on the URL. It would be better to have all the jquery stuff in JS functions, and have PHP write into the <script> in your page something that will call the functions you need. inside a $(document).ready(), of course.

Comment: @MightyPork Is it a big problem if I depend on the url? Why is that wrong? I thought about using PHP for this solution, but I thought adding the script in the head if inside the url give more weight to the website.

Comment: I just think it's a bad practice, but if you like it, keep it. Reasons - for example, if you one day decide to rename the url from gallery to photos, the script will suddenly stop working.

Comment: @MightyPork So which other method would you use to not depend on a url? Because even if you use php you will have to depend on the url right? That is the only way to target this page or should I use data-role of HTML5? Open for suggestions.